# Karate-UI Automation - How to close Location allowance window (Chrome)

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, karate

I am using Karate-UI Automation Software. I run my test scenario under Chrome browser. When I go to page where map is displayed (e.g. Mapbox) user is asked about Location allowance (screenshot) with buttons Allow and Deny. Is there some easy trick to confirm/deny/close dialog in scenario step? - in feature file.

[location allowance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kSx5.jpg)

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the Chrome dialog that does not impact the flow of the test but just stays there and is somewhat irritating ? I'm sorry I haven't found a way to suppress that. Would be great if someone can find a way, I have tried all the flags here, but none of them worked: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

We are experimenting with [Karate-Robot](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot) to be able to handle some of these use-cases, but this is still experimental. We need people to try and contribute fixes, if you use this - take 0.9.6.RC1 because 0.9.5 has some issues.

Finally if you are facing a problem with plain HTML, please follow this process so that we can try and figure a solution or enhance the Karate syntax if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is, the webpage do not load desirable elements until the Location allowance is closed... I can get over it in some different wat.

Comment: @RadimBukovský ok then most likely one of the command-line switches (see link in answer) will solve this, can you experiment - and if it needs to be added by default we can do it - refer `addOptions` key: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driver-configuration

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly if you use chromedriver. Refer below code snippet which currently I am using.

```
Background: 
* def session = { capabilities: { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': { args: [ '--disable-geolocation', '--test-type' ] } } } }
* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', port: 9515, executable: '<Path to chromedriver>', webDriverSession: '#(session)'}
```