# How can I handle Geo Location popup in browser using karate?

Tags: karate

I need to allow the geo location during my karate web automation test.
I was going through this documentation https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core
It has information on handling dialog boxes and popup but they don't seem to be working for the geo location pop up

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767551/how-can-i-handle-geo-location-popup-in-browser-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment above, looks like for Chrome you can use the `addOptions` to pass `disable-geolocation`:

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', addOptions: [`disable-geolocation`] }
```

I guess it would be similar for other browsers. If needed please consider submitting a PR to the project.

Also note that we are working on [Karate Robot](https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/1253373486384295936) that may be able to solve this in the future.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I used that with below config and it works fine.


`* configure driverTarget = { docker: 'ptrthomas/karate-chrome', showDriverLog: true , addOptions: [ 'disable-geolocation' ]}`

Comment: I tried but it shows me this message. 

'
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. '

Comment: don't bother then

Comment: Can something like this be used to escape the geo location pop up, ` * input('body', Key.ESCAPE)` , I was going through these articles 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951153/karate-ui-automation-how-to-press-key-without-necessity-to-be-in-input-field 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948829/karate-ui-automation-how-to-close-location-allowance-window-chrome and seems like both the problems can be solved in case KEY.ESCAPE work in karate script on full body ?

Comment: @salilgupta12 try it and see, and update so we can all learn from you

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Actually I had tried and as it did not work, hence I thought I will cross check with you in case I am missing something here. I have tried manually, pressing escape makes the geo location pop up go away but in script using ` * input('body', Key.ESCAPE)` does not seem working, so any suggestions on this?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475 - but do try and submit an example for us to analyze and make any fixes to the core framework if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue