# How to handle Geo location popup in chrome browser using KARATE

Tags: karate

**i'm trying with this code but i can't get an expected behavior.**

[Geolocation popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQeQH.png)

```
* configure driver = {type:'chrome', addOptions:['--disable-geolocation', '--disable-extensions',  '--test-type'], webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities: { "goog:chromeOptions": { useAutomationExtension: false} } } }
* driver 'https://es.infobyip.com/browsergeolocation.php'
```

Comment: as per this thread it is supposed to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61907860/143475 - maybe you can contribute code or research and help us fix it

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly if you use chromedriver.
Refer below code snippet which currently I am using.

```
Background: 
* def session = { capabilities: { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': { args: [ '--disable-geolocation', '--test-type' ] } } } }
* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', port: 9515, executable: '<Path to chromedriver>', webDriverSession: '#(session)'}
```